# R : How to fill an array with this peculiar calculation?

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop

I would fill an array `D` with a loop, and only with a loop (please), where my data are structured in this particular way:

```
 A <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=12,ncol=10))
 c_2 <- c(0.003,0.004) 
 an <- sapply(c_2,function(x) x*c(1:12))
 B <-array(an,c(12,1,2))
 set.seed(1)
 C<- rnorm(10,0.6,0.1)
 D <- array(NA,c(12,1,20))
 f_12 <- exp(c(0:11)/12)

for (k in 1:length(A)){       
          for (i in 1:dim(B)[3]){          
            for (z in 1:length(C)){
                    M_nat <- C[z]
                  A[,z] <- f_12*M_nat
                ris_1 <- A[,k]                  
             cost_1 <- B[,,i]
            prov_1 <-  cost_1*ris_1
           D[,,k*i] <- prov_1
            }           
          }
        }
```

My expected result is an array `D`, where each `[,,z]` dimension is a result from `B[,,1]` and `B[,,2]` for each column of `A`(`A` in the loop).

With the above code the R result is an array where the first ten `z` dimension are full, and after, some have values, and others are NA. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: In addition to be full, are the first 10 z dimensions accurately representing the data in the way you wanted?

Comment: Yes, the first 10z dimension representing the data correctly!

Comment: Why this strange fixation on using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outer(1:10, 1:2, "*")` tells you which indices you can fill with  `D[,,k*i]`:

```
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    2    4
# [3,]    3    6
# [4,]    4    8
# [5,]    5   10
# [6,]    6   12
# [7,]    7   14
# [8,]    8   16
# [9,]    9   18
#[10,]   10   20
```

These are the ones not possible:

```
(1:20)[!(1:20 %in% outer(1:10, 1:2, "*"))]
#[1] 11 13 15 17 19
```

And indeed, those elements are not filled in `D`. Note that you filled some elements more than once.

You could use `(i-1) * 10 + k` instead if `k*i`.

Comment: All the best Roland!